# Class not found [ Laravel 5.5, production project]

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, cpanel, bluehost

I'm working with Laravel 5.5. I uploaded my project to server. But I got error which my project works fine local server.

> Class 'App\Models\Textbox\TextBox' not found
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError

I know, I just run `composer dump-autoload` and its works fine. But main problem is main hosting server is bluehost/cpanel. I can't run any command with shell, because it say ***your account not verified*** and I can't do this, because account not mine.

But I looked for alternative solutions and just upload these folders to server after run `dump-autoload` in local server.

```
\bootstrap
\vendor\composer
```

But it doesn't work. Finally I just upload all of `vendor` folder and don't get any result.

Do I have to run `dump-autoload` only server `commandline`/`bash` ?
 Can I solve this without run any `commandline` query in server  ?

P.S. I looked all of related questions and all of solution from google but I can't make it ready for work :(

This is my folder structure:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Set correct path for model TextBox

Comment: what do you mean , "path" ?, All path-s are correct

Comment: declare TextBox at top the file like use App\Models\Textbox\TextBox;
correct this path

Comment: I just updated my question, I added my folder structure. Everything is correct. If any path is wrong , it wouldn't work. But project works fine in local server :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mind case of your class name.

As you see you get error:

```
App\Models\Textbox\TextBox
```

but your class is:

```
App\Models\TextBox\TextBox
```

so as you see directory / namespace is with capital B.

This is important for composer autoloading to have exact same classname and directory with valid case (assuming you are using `PSR-4` but this is default for Laravel).

On Windows file/directory case doesn't matter so you can write your namespace also TEXTBOX (for Windows `TEXTBOX` directory is the same as `textbox`), but on Linux server there is no `TEXTBOX` directory, there is no `Textbox` directory - there is only `TextBox` directory so it won't be possible to autoload class and that's why you are getting the error on production and on localhost it's working fine.

Comment: Your namesace might still be declared in lower case. Remember that when you develop on a Windows machine your file system is case insensitive, but when you deploy to a Linux machine the folder name has to be spelled with the correct case.

Comment: @JonasSchwabe really? Thanks for good point. I don't know about it. Yeah I run this project in local server without any problem, but server made some problem for me :)